# Make regular expression to match subject codes

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have some subject codes in excel. There will be 3 cases in a single cell. I am using VBA to handle the following.

```
Case 1: Single subject in a cell

ABC1000

Case 2: Multiple "And" subjects in a cell

ABC1000 + 1234 + CJ43 + ......

Case 3: Multiple "Or" subjects in a cell

ABC1000 / BlaAdc / CJ43 / .........
```

Currently, my intention is that if someone enter the following invalid cases in a cell. An error msg box will popup.

```
* ABC1000 + + bla200
* ABC1000 + bla200 / CJ43
* Nothing in the cell
* ABC1000 & bla200
* ABC1000 && bla200
* ABC1000 OR bla200
* ABC1000 or bla200
* Criminology 301
* And more......
```

It exceeds my ability so I need some helps here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of an efficient way to do this if you are executing the code each time a user makes a change to a cell i.e. validating their entry.

You could use a construct tied to a worksheet change event that went along the lines of:

```
myStr = target.Value   'e.g. "ABC1000 + + bla200"

If myStr = "" Then MsgBox "Invalid entry"

If InStr(1, myStr, " ") > 0 Then MsgBox "Invalid entry"

If InStr(1, myStr, "+") > 0 And InStr(1, myStr, "\") > 0 Then MsgBox "Invalid entry"

If InStr(1, myStr, "++") > 0 Then MsgBox "Invalid entry"

If InStr(1, myStr, "&") > 0 Then MsgBox "Invalid entry"

If InStr(1, myStr, "&&") > 0 Then MsgBox "Invalid entry"
```

You would build your list of test conditions and use InStr rather than a regex.

You could condense perhaps into a Select Case

```
Select Case True
Case InStr(1, myStr, "+") > 0 And InStr(1, myStr, "\") > 0, myStr = vbNullString, InStr(1, myStr, " ") > 0, _
     InStr(1, myStr, "++") > 0, InStr(1, myStr, "&") > 0, InStr(1, myStr, "&&") > 0
    MsgBox "Invalid entry"
End Select
```

Comment: Hi, may I ask how I embed the excel function to entire column. This is also for future column that user will input?

Comment: Hi, Is your comment meant to be below @FunThomas's response?

Comment: Actually, for both of you.

Comment: 1) vba:  loop through the column from start row to end row applying function or 2) in an adjacent column to the one whose values you want to test, put on each cell the formula =testSyntax. Should appear as you start to type. Function returns  a Boolean (true false) and exits if cell is blank. You would need to amend for your desired msgbox , perhaps with if testSyntax = false then msgbox "msg". Also, think about your blank cell test condition as cells will start presumably start blank.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must understand your grammar first to identify the possible errors. If I understand you correct:

- There are 2 different operators in your expressions, but it's not allowed 
  to have a mixture of them. Operators are `+` and `/` (and nothing else)
- Anything except these operators are seen as terms.
- A blank splits terms.
- If you have more than a term, terms must be separated by an operator.

I wouldn't try to solve this with a regex, but with an UDF. I played a little bit, this is my attempt:

```
Function testSyntax(inputStr As String) As Boolean
Const OperatorOR = "/"
Const OperatorAND = "+"

testSyntax = False
Dim s As String, orParts() As String, andParts() As String
s = Trim(inputStr)
If s = "" Then Exit Function     ' Empty string

' split parts
orParts = Split(s, OperatorOR)
andParts = Split(s, OperatorAND)

If UBound(orParts) > 0 And UBound(andParts) > 0 Then Exit Function  ' mixed operators
Dim i As Integer, p As String
If UBound(orParts) > 0 Then
    ' Or-operator used.
    For i = 0 To UBound(orParts)
        p = Trim(orParts(i))
        If p = "" Or InStr(p, " ") > 0 Or InStr(p, vbTab) > 0 Then Exit Function   ' 2 terms or 2 OR operators in row
    Next i
Else
    ' And-operator used (or only 1 term)
    For i = 0 To UBound(andParts)
        p = Trim(andParts(i))
        If p = "" Or InStr(p, " ") > 0 Or InStr(p, vbTab) > 0 Then Exit Function   ' 2 terms or 2 AND operators in row
    Next i
End If
testSyntax = True

End Function
```

Comment: Good. I will give it a test